# What is equivalent of CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER in java httpurlconnection

Tags: java, curl

I need to send some data in header of my request to the server.
I searched many times but didn't find a way to set header of request in java.
many people said things about `httpurlconnection.setrequestproperty` but that's another feature which is equal to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.
anyway to set the header of request?